# How to load Google ClusterData 2019 traces in BigQuery Console?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, dataset

I want to load the following dataset into BigQuery Console -
https://research.google/tools/datasets/google-cluster-workload-traces-2019/

Can someone tell me how can I load the dataset and see all the tables in Cloud Console.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see in this [document](https://drive.google.com/file/d/10r6cnJ5cJ89fPWCgj7j4LtLBqYN9RiI9/view), the datasets are only provided through `BigQuery`. As its already provided on BigQuery you don't need to load it, only access.

To pin the datasets to your console, follow this steps:

1. Go to BigQuery Console
2. Click in the **+ Add Data** button in the left bar just above the projects list
3. Click in **Pin a Project**
4. Enter the project name **google.com:google-cluster-data**
5. Click in **Pin**

After that you will be able to see the project and its datasets in the left bar.